# Python BeautifulSoup returning wrong list of inputs from find_all()

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have Python 2.7.3 and bs.**version** is 4.4.1

For some reason this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # parsing

html = """
<html>
<head id="Head1"><title>Title</title></head>
<body>
    <form id="form" action="login.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="text" name="email" >
        <input type="button" name="Submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
"""

html_proc = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for form in  html_proc.find_all('form'):
    for input in form.find_all('input'):
        print "input:" + str(input)
```

returns a wrong list of inputs:

```
input:<input name="fname" type="text">
<input name="email" type="text">
<input name="Submit" type="button" value="submit">
</input></input></input>
input:<input name="email" type="text">
<input name="Submit" type="button" value="submit">
</input></input>
input:<input name="Submit" type="button" value="submit">
</input>
```

It's supposed to return

```
input: <input name="fname" type="text">
input: <input type="text" name="email">
input: <input type="button" name="Submit" value="submit">
```

What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, this looks like an artifact of the html parser.  Using `'lxml'` for the parser instead of `'html.parser'` seems to make it work.  The downside of this is that you (or your users) then need to install `lxml` -- The upside is that `lxml` is a better/faster parser ;-).

As for *why* `'html.parser'` doesn't seem to work correctly in this case, I think it has something to do with the fact that `input` tags are self-closing.  If you explicitly close your inputs, it works:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" ></input>
<input type="text" name="email" ></input>
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="submit" ></input>
```

I would be curious to see if we could modify the source code to handle this case ... Doing a little experiment to monkey-patch `bs4` indicates that we *can* do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from bs4.builder import _htmlparser

# Monkey-patch the Beautiful soup HTML parser to close input tags automatically.
BeautifulSoupHTMLParser = _htmlparser.BeautifulSoupHTMLParser
class FixedParser(BeautifulSoupHTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, name, attrs):
        # Old-style class... No super :-(
        result = BeautifulSoupHTMLParser.handle_starttag(self, name, attrs)
        if name.lower() == 'input':
            self.handle_endtag(name)
        return result

_htmlparser.BeautifulSoupHTMLParser = FixedParser


html = """
<html>
<head id="Head1"><title>Title</title></head>
<body>
    <form id="form" action="login.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="fname" >
        <input type="text" name="email" >
        <input type="button" name="Submit" value="submit" >
    </form>
</body>

</html>
"""

html_proc = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for form in  html_proc.find_all('form'):
    for input in form.find_all('input'):
        print "input:" + str(input)
```

Obviously, this isn't a *true* fix (I wouldn't submit this as a patch to the BS4 folks), but it does demonstrate the problem.  Since there is no end-tag, the `handle_endtag` method is never getting called.  If we call it ourselves, things tend to work out (as long as the html doesn't *also* have a closing input tag ...).

I'm not really sure whose responsibility this bug should be, but I suppose that you could start by submitting it to bs4 -- They might then forward you on to report a bug on the python tracker, I'm not sure...

Comment: Thanks. This works. It's odd that I have to end my inputs with </input> because that's not standard HTML code. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp and if someone can report this to the proper people, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Arrow -- I would probably start by reporting the bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use nested loop for this,** and use `lxml` , Change your code to this:

```
inp = []
html_proc = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for form in  html_proc.find_all('form'):
    inp.extend(form.find_all('input'))

for item in inp:    
    print "input:" + str(item)
```